# OEM Legislation

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, trademark, intellectual-property

As an OEM, is it legal to use branded motherboards, such as ASUS in our own enclosures. I am aware that the other parts get used by major computer makers such as HP. However they usually make their own motherboard or get a third party to make it but brand it as their own.

I wish to use a branded motherboard instead so do I need to do anything to make sure I still oblige to the law.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't? If you were building a car would you think you couldn't use Toyota parts in its engine?

Comment: because the only thing in a standard laptop that is usually branded by the PC maker is the motherboard so maybe using that in a commercial  product requires permission?
retail and OEM are different things. For retailers its fine to get parts from other companies, however OEM's use different licensing to what retail hardware and software does.

OEM generally means that something is 'attached' to a certain PC, retail means it can be used or duplicated on several systems.

Comment: So, what does your contract say then?

Comment: there is no contract so far, I don't know what motherboards to get yet
note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_reseller, usually parts that play a role in an end product come from OEM's however in the case of motherboards the company that has end product is the OEM.

Comment: Are you planning on selling these items? Have all the oem parts been acquired legally? What country is this question for? Could you give more details about what it is you're doing?

Comment: I am planning on selling them yes, the parts will be bought legally and it is in the UK. We make computers that are pre built using a customization tool on the sites web page, however we sell pre fabricated computers too, those also are what we put on display to attract customers who are interested. Once a user has built a PC its sent to the company and we purchase the parts needed, and build it, then sell it to the customer to make a return.
I have read that the buisness needs to be:
A: Registered in the UK  
B: Applied for self tax assessment  
C: Must have a strategic export control license

Comment: the overall computer is branded as ours (I.E the computer case has our logo on)